# How to enable Apple Pay for connect accounts in Stripe?

Tags: .net, angular, stripe-payments

I'm trying to enable wallet payments like Google Pay and Apple Pay in my Angular application using Stripe.

I'm using connected accounts, the payment is managed by the backend with the `PaymentIntent`.

So the flow is the following:

1. Transaction created via backend
2. `ClientSecret` is returned to Angular
3. `StripePaymentElement` is created with the `ClientSecret`
4. Webhook captures `charge.succeed` and completes the order

The issue here is that only Google Pay is working, If I try to open the payment from an apple device, I will be able only to use credit card as payment.

I've registered the domains in the dashboard, but after reading the documentation I've found that I need to [create the domains for connected accounts via API](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/pmd-registration?platform=api#register-your-domain-while-using-connect).

At this point, when the domain should be created? Should I do it inside the method where I create the transaction in my backend?

The method which creates the transaction looks like this:

```
private string CreateStripeTransaction(string paymentId, string orderId, string type = "MENU")
{
    var keys = GetPaymentKeys(paymentId);

    StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = GetStripeKey();

    var amount = GetOrderAmount(orderId);
    var service = new PaymentIntentService();
    var options = new PaymentIntentCreateOptions
    {
        Amount = amount,
        Currency = "eur",
        Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>
         {
             { "integration_check", "accept_a_payment" },
             { "OrderId", orderId },
             { "PaymentId", paymentId },
             { "Company", _company },
             { "Type", type }
         },
    };

    var requestOptions = new RequestOptions
    {
        StripeAccount = keys.publicKey
    };

    var intent = service.Create(options, requestOptions);

    return JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { client_secret = intent.ClientSecret });
}
```

Then the `ClientSecret` is consumed like this:

```
  async initStripe() {
    this.stripe = await loadStripe(
      environment.STRIPE,
      {
        stripeAccount: this.publicKey,
      }
    );

    this.paymentService
    .createTransaction(this.paymentId, this.orderId, this.type, 'stripe')
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      const clientSecret = data.client_secret;
      const elements = this.stripe.elements({ clientSecret });
      const options: StripePaymentElementOptions = {
        layout: "accordion"
      };
      this.card = elements.create('payment', options);
      this.card.mount(this.cardElement.nativeElement);
      this.card.on('change', this.cardHandler);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the domain only by following the [official guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/pmd-registration?platform=api#register-your-domain-while-using-connect) is not enough, after having a talk with stripe support, I've been able to resolve the issue by following these steps:

1. [Listing all the ApplePay domains for the connected account](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/tests/Stripe/ApplePayDomainTest.php#L21)
2. Check if the domain you're trying to activate stripe for is listed
3. [Delete the domain](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/tests/Stripe/ApplePayDomainTest.php#L55)
4. [Recreate the domain](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/tests/Stripe/ApplePayDomainTest.php#L42-L44)

Answer (score 0):

Not only you need to register the domain, you also need to make sure you alo [verify your domain with Apple Pay](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/pmd-registration?platform=api#verify-your-domain-with-apple-pay)

Comment: Yes I have yet done the verification, but the issue still seems to be that it's a Connect acount as in the console I still get: `You have not registered or verified the domain`